# $n_1n_2^{-1} \in M\cap N \Rightarrow n_1(M \cap N)=n_2(M \cap N)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does this hold:

$n_1n_2^{-1} \in M\cap N \Rightarrow n_1(M \cap N)=n_2(M \cap N)$

($M$, $N$ are groups. $n_1$, $n_2 \in N$.)

Comment: When you write $n_1(M \cap N)$, you are talking about the left coset of $M \cap N$ with representative $n_1$, correct?

Comment: Are $M$ and $N$ subgroups of some larger group $G$?

Comment: @Sammy Black: Yes, they are sub normal groups of a group G and G=MN

Comment: I think you mean both $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$, then $M\cap N$ is normal also, and your statement is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $ G$,  then $M\cap N$ is also a normal subgroup of $G$, in which case, your statement is true,

...since for any normal subgroup $H$ of $G$, if $n_1n_2^{-1} \in H$, then $n_1H = n_2H$. Here, we just have that $H = M \cap N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.